# How can I proportionally scale a UV Map when scaling the object

Tags: uv, node-editor

I have a mapping node connected to an image texture to tile a carpet image on a plane. The results are OK until I scale the object. I am looking for a way to scale the plane without enlarging the carpet image texture.

Node setup: UV Map -> Mapping -> Image -> BSDF -> Output
[image: Image node setup]

OK result

[image: OK result]

After I scale the plane the carpet texture is too large. I know I can go back to scale the texture but is there a way where I do not have to do that?

[image: image texture is too large]

IDK if it matters, but I want to keep this in EEVEE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to use *Object Coordinates* and an *Empty*.
The texture will then keep its size when objects are scaled.

1. Add an ampty to your scene
2. Set texture coordinates to *Object* and **target your empty**
3. Adjust the texture position/size by moving/scaling the empty or via the Mapping node.

[image]